# How a wrong idea can lead to a good description?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics

In Feymann Lectures: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_43.html [1], is used the idea of $N=T\divτ$ to be the number os collision that a particle in a ideal gas (whose is at equilibrium) suffers while it pss a time T and $τ$ being a proportionality constant.

Let us use again $N(t)$ but now as the number of particles that had not experienced a collision at time $t$, so between this time $t$ and a small amount of time dt one can assume that the number of particles whose experienced a collision is $N(t)\dot{}dt\divτ$, but if we use $dt=τ$, even $τ$ being small with would lead us to conclude that all the particles had a collisio.

Clearly from experiences we do not expect this. But even with this issue, using this idea as basis one may reach[1]:
$N(t)=N_0e^{−t/τ}$ wht describes better what really happens, because if now we use $t$ to $τ$ we will not conclude that all particules had colided.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, starting from a number of particles $N_0$ at $t=0$ you want to know the number $N(t)$ of particles that have not experienced a collision in a gas. The number of particles that experience a collision in an infinitesimal time $dt$ is proportional to the number $N(t)$ of particles at time $t$ with the proportionality constant $\frac{1}{\tau}$. Thus the infinitesimal decrease of the number is    $$dN(t)=-\frac{1}{\tau}N(t)dt$$ From this you cannot conclude that for $dt=\tau$ the decrease of $N(t)$ will be $dN(t)=-N(t)$ because $dt$ and thus $dN(t)$ are assumed to be infinitesimal, that means arbitrarily small. Certainly much smaller than $\tau$. The constant $\tau$ turns out to be the time that the number decreases by a factor $\frac{1}{e}$ according to the exponential law $$N(t)=N_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$ The constant $\tau$ is also called mean time between collisions.

Comment: Thank you, it is more clearly now. But if may i asked just more thing, why is this tau constant called mean? what kind of mean propiert it have? Despite the property of decrease by a factor of e^-1

Comment: @Yassin Rany - That $\tau$ is the mean time between collisions can be seen by averaging time $t$  over the fraction of particles that have a collision in a time interval $(t, t+t+dt)$ $$\int_{N_0}^0  t\frac {-dN}{N_0}=\int_0^∞ -t\frac{1}{\tau}e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}dt=\tau$$

Comment: @Yassin Rany - The correct averaging intergral is $$\int_0^∞ \frac{t}{\tau}e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}dt=\tau$$